# nginx allow all doesn't work

Tags: configuration, nginx

I am trying to allow pinterest to access to my dev site's images, currently nginx deny.conf is using `auth_basic` and a list of allow IPs. There is no `deny all` in there. `satisfy any` is also in deny.conf

I added `allow all`to my site's config and restarted/reloaded nginx but still getting access denied from pinterest.

```
location ^~ ^/(cache|media|static)/ {
        allow all;
        access_log off;
        expires 1y;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting `satisfy any;` in your configuration. That tells Nginx to accept either HTTP authentication or IP restriction. By default, when you define both, it will expect both.

> Allows access if all (all) or at least one (any) of the
> ngx_http_access_module, ngx_http_auth_basic_module,
> ngx_http_auth_request_module, or ngx_http_auth_jwt_module modules
> allow access.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> location / {
>     satisfy any;
>
>     allow 192.168.1.0/32;
>     deny  all;
>
>     auth_basic           "closed site";
>     auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
> }
> ```

[Source](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#satisfy)